Is there any Rest API available for retrieving Pinned documents
For SharePoint Subscription Edition, is there any Rest API available for retrieving Pinned documents based on the site collection accessed by the user?
I checked few blogs but unable to find any information on accessing the information through API's.

In SharePoint Subscription Edition, you can use the SharePoint REST API to interact with various SharePoint data, including retrieving pinned documents. However, there isn’t a specific REST endpoint dedicated solely to retrieving pinned documents.
Instead, you can use the general SharePoint REST API to query for documents and then filter or sort them based on your criteria.
You can then apply filters or sorting to retrieve the pinned documents.
For example:
https://<your-sharepoint-site>/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('<your-list-title>')/items?$filter=IsPinned eq true

